# how to calculate indices when doing csr_matrix addition?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am learning scipy codes for sparse matrix operations. However, I am puzzled with how csr_matrix indices calculated When doing addition operation. my code is simple:

```
B = A + A.T
A.toarray()
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
A.indices:
array([ 0,  2,  1,  5, 10,  3,  6, 11,  9,  8,  
    1,  2,  9, 10,  5,  8,  6, 11,  3,  7,  
    2, 10,  1,  5,  9,  6, 11,  7,  8,  3,  
    3,  8,  6,  7,  5, 11,  9, 10,  2,  1,  
    4,  9,  1,  7,  8, 11,  3,  6, 10,  5,  
    5,  6, 11, 10,  8,  9,  3,  2,  7,  1,  
    6,  5,  8, 11,  9, 10,  3,  7,  2,  1,  
    7,  9,  3,  6,  8,  5, 11, 10,  2,  1,  
    8,  6, 11,  9,  5,  3, 10,  7,  1,  2,  
    9, 11, 10,  8,  6,  5,  7,  3,  2,  1, 
    10, 11, 5,  9,  6,  8,  2,  3,  1,  7, 
    11, 10,  5,  6,  8,  9,  3,  7,  2, 1], dtype=int32)
```

I debuged the code for diving into scipy for more details and found that .T operation makes matrix A into CSC format matrix. And then, in addition overload operation, A.T will be converted into CSR format matrix again, but with its indices changed like below:

```
A.T.toarray():
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
A.T.indices:
array([ 0,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,  2,  3,
    5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
   10, 11,  4,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,
    2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,
    8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,
    1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,
    6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
   11], dtype=int32)
```

what I cannot understand is the B.indices, shown below:

```
B.toarray()
array([[2., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
   [1., 2., 2., 2., 0., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
   [1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
   [0., 1., 0., 1., 2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
   [1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
   [1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
   [0., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
   [1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
   [1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
   [1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
   [1., 2., 2., 2., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]])
B.indices
array([ 8,  9, 11,  6,  3, 10,  5,  1,  2,  0,  
    4,  0,  7,  3, 11,  6,  8,  5, 10,  9,  2,  1,  
    0,  3,  8,  7, 11,  6,  9,  5,  1, 10,  2,  
    4,  0,  1,  2, 10,  9, 11,  5,  7,  6,  8,  3,  
    5, 10,  6,  3, 11,  8,  7,  1,  9,  4,
    4,  0,  1,  7,  2,  3,  9,  8, 10, 11,  6,  5,  
    4,  0,  1,  2,  7,  3, 10,  9, 11,  8,  5,  6,  
    4,  1,  2, 10, 11,  5,  8,  6,  3,  9,  7,  
    4,  0,  2,  1,  7, 10,  3,  5,  9, 11,  6,  8,
    4,  0,  1,  2,  3,  7,  5,  6,  8, 10, 11,  9,  
    4,  0,  7,  1,  3,  2,  8,  6,  9,  5, 11, 10,  
    4,  0,  1,  2,  7,  3,  9,  8,  6,  5, 10, 11], dtype=int32)
```

The result B is calculated via C++ so library _sparsetools.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in scipy, thusly I cannot get its code.

This problem almost drives me crazy. Hope some of you can help me.

Comment: I think you are making things too complicated for yourself.  Your `A` is larger and denser than needed for testing.  The addition for `A+A.T` isn't any different than the addition to two unrelated matrices (as long as they match in shape), `B = A1 + A2`.  A logical method, assuming both are `csr`, is iterate by rows.  The indices for the `B` row will be a union of the `A1` and `A2` ones.  Sums that equal 0 can be removed now, and at a final `B.eliminate_zeros()` call.

Comment: Your `A.T.indices` is actually `A.T.tocsr().indices`, isn't it?  Making the `csr` copy sort the indices.

Answer (score 1):

If I make `A` from your `A.todense()` display:

```
In [156]: A = np.array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
     ...:    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

and a sparse from that:

```
In [159]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(A)
In [160]: M
Out[160]: 
<12x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 120 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [162]: M.indices
Out[162]: 
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,
        9, 10, 11,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  2,  3,  5,
        6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,
        2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
       10, 11,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,
        7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  2,
        3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  1,  2,  3,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
       11], dtype=int32)
```

These indices are not the same as yours - or that they are the same but sorted by row:

```
In [164]: for i in range(12):
     ...:     print(M.indices[M.indptr[i]:M.indptr[i+1]])
     ...:     
[ 0  1  2  3  5  6  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
```

And for the `csr` version of its transpose:

```
In [165]: M1 = M.T.tocsr()
In [166]: for i in range(12):
     ...:     print(M1.indices[M1.indptr[i]:M1.indptr[i+1]])

[0]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[4]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
```

Making the transpose by switching to a `csc` format, with same attributes, is fast, but as you note to do the addition it has convert back to `csr`.

And then taking the sum:

```
In [167]: B = M+M.T
In [168]: for i in range(12):
     ...:     print(B.indices[B.indptr[i]:B.indptr[i+1]])

[ 0  1  2  3  5  6  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
```

Since the `M` indices are ordered by row, the pattern is fairly obvious.

```
In [172]: M.has_sorted_indices
Out[172]: True
```

My versions are also `canonical`.

All the rows of `A` have 10 nonzero terms.  `B` has 10, 11, 12; the transpose as filled in 0-2 nonzeros.

Your `A` has non-sorted indices.  The `A.T.indices` are sorted.  I suppose one might deduce something about the evaluation method by comparing the unordered `B.indices` with the `A.indices`.  But is it worth it?

===

I recreated your noncanonical matrices with:

```
In [186]: altindices = np.array([ 0,  2,  1,  5, 10,  3,  6, 11,  9,  8,  
     ...:     1,  2,  9, 10,  5,  8,  6, 11,  3,  7,  
     ...:     2, 10,  1,  5,  9,  6, 11,  7,  8,  3,  
     ...:     3,  8,  6,  7,  5, 11,  9, 10,  2,  1,  
     ...:     4,  9,  1,  7,  8, 11,  3,  6, 10,  5,  
     ...:     5,  6, 11, 10,  8,  9,  3,  2,  7,  1,  
     ...:     6,  5,  8, 11,  9, 10,  3,  7,  2,  1,  
     ...:     7,  9,  3,  6,  8,  5, 11, 10,  2,  1,  
     ...:     8,  6, 11,  9,  5,  3, 10,  7,  1,  2,  
     ...:     9, 11, 10,  8,  6,  5,  7,  3,  2,  1, 
     ...:     10, 11, 5,  9,  6,  8,  2,  3,  1,  7, 
     ...:     11, 10,  5,  6,  8,  9,  3,  7,  2, 1], dtype='int32')
    In [188]: M2 = sparse.csr_matrix((M.data, altindices, M.indptr))
```

`M2.T.indices` are the same as `M2.indices` (the `csc` equivalent), but `M2.T.tocsr()` are sorted as you display.  `B2 = M2+M2.T` has the indices as yours.

If I evaluate just one row, I get the same indices, confirming my guess that it performs the sum row by row (iterating with `indptr` as do above):

```
In [194]: M2[0,:]+(M2.T)[0,:]
Out[194]: 
<1x12 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [195]: _.indices
Out[195]: array([ 8,  9, 11,  6,  3, 10,  5,  1,  2,  0], dtype=int32)
```